# Is there a way to modify the path for ".." ( shortcut )?

Tags: matlab, path

Whenever I download repositories from my team from other departments they have scripts ( .m files )in MATLAB which are runned from a path file which contain ".." ( like a shortcut ) in their path link and I do not know how to change that on my MATLAB workstation, the parent directory for it. For example an .m file (script) which contains:

```
MODEL_CONFIG='..\03_config\config.m';
run(MODEL_CONFIG)
```

On their workstation this code works but on my workstation it says that:
**"there is no ..\03_config\config.m not found."**

and I know that the ".." is the parent directory from the project. My question is:
"How can I change the default parent directory so that ".." can work on my workstation too?

Right now the only solution is to manually change in every script file the ".." with 'C:\Users%user%\Desktop\19_projectsMatlab\99_GSM_OEM' - and it this example 99_GSM_OEM would be the parent directory.

Comment: In general you should set up the project folder structure the same way as the other members of the team, so that the relative paths all work.

Comment: Yes man, I am doing that, but he has an username and I had other username .... 

C:\Users\teambrazil1012\Desktop\19_projectsMatlab\99_GSM_OEM

and mine is 

C:\Users\teamargentina20222\Desktop\19_projectsMatlab\99_GSM_OEM

Do you have a solution?

Comment: Relative paths would not be affected by the folder above the root of the project (that is really the point of using them). Any other clues?

Comment: 1)  What is the entire path to this file that contains this code? 2) What is the entire path to the `config.m` file that this code refers to?

Comment: You probably what to change your current directory in MATLAB to the project directory, so that `../03_config` is a valid path.

Comment: Yes Chris! That is what I want but somehow when I change it, it doesn't change. I use the function "userpath". Is it correct?

Comment: No, you need to use [`cd`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cd.html), or do it through the GUI.

Comment: Actually I am stupid. ".." is like "cd.." in MS-DOS....
I was in the wrong folder all the time. I am not supposed to be in the parent directory of the project. I am supposed to be in the folder directory where the main script is running (main.m).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I am stupid. ".." is like "cd.." in MS-DOS....
I was in the wrong folder all the time. I am not supposed to be in the parent directory of the project when I run the main script. I am supposed to be in the folder directory where the main script is running (main.m).

So when I am in the folder directory of the main.m file the following link:

```
MODEL_CONFIG='..\03_config\config.m';
```

says go back with one folder from where the main.m file is and there should be the folder 03_config which you access. Thank you guys.

And if you have more subfolders in the folder in which is the main.m script "." - means the current location....

Answer (score 1):

What a `..` means in a path is basically: go back one folder from your current working directory in Matlab. You can easily change this folder by clicking on [image: this button] in Matlab.
If you want to change this folder during script execution you can do this with
cd 'C:/Users/yourname/yourfolder/'

Comment: Good point. Some IDEs (so perhaps MatLab) have a concept of the "current directory" being set in the IDE and code execution treating that setting as the root folder of the project.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem.

../ used to work well. I hade some old code a few years ago using "../" in paths and file expressions that work very well. Now with my new computer and Matlab 2022, the same expression does not work and report the same issue..

Perhaps Matlab changes something, and hope that they will notice this and change it back.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).